# ASP.Net Core routes with Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Web API Controller with a method called `GetHeroes()` and it doesn't get called by the front end. I can get a simple `Get()` method to work but there doesn't seem to be a way to name methods and have these methods called.

**CharactersController.cs**

```
[Route("api/{controller}/{action}")]
public class CharactersController : Controller
{

    private readonly ICharacterRepository _characterRepository;

    public CharactersController(ICharacterRepository characterRepository)
    {
        _characterRepository = characterRepository;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Character> GetHeroes()
    {
        return _characterRepository.ListAll().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
    getItems() {
    this.http.get('api/characters/getheroes').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(items => {
        this._collectionObserver.next(items);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify route and parameters in HttpGet attribute. Have you tried something like this?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CharactersController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpGet("GetHeroes")] // Here comes method name
    public IEnumerable<Character> GetHeroes()
    {
        return _characterRepository.ListAll().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Here is a good article about routing:
[Custom Routing and Action Method Names in ASP.NET 5 and ASP.NET MVC 6](http://www.ryadel.com/en/custom-routing-method-names-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/)

Answer (score 2):

This works for ASP.NET Core:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetHero")]
    public IActionResult GetById(string id)
    {
        var hero = Heroes.Find(id);
        if (hero == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(hero);
    }
```